# How to implement animation for text form field in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter application. In my application, I like to animate the text field just like the CVV text filed in this link https://dribbble.com/shots/4542183-e-commerce-shopping-app-UI-Kit-interaction. I could see few references on how to change the color or width of the text box border in flutter. But this is something different - a running border. I have attached a needed animation video link below for reference. Is there any way to achieve that text form field border animation in flutter?

Refer link : https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/692322/screenshots/4542183/attachments/1027997/payment_interaction.mp4